# Rails: Querying through 2 join table associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a quite complicated relation between models and are now frustrated by a SQL Query to retrieve some objects.

given a *Product model* connected to a *category model* via a has_many :through association and a joint table *categorization*.
Also a *User model* connected to this *category model* via a has_many :through association and a joint table *category_friendship*.

I am now facing the problem to retrieve all products, which are within the categories of the array user.category_ids. However, I can't just not manage to write the WHERE statement properly.

I tried this:

```
u = User.first
uc = u.category_ids
Product.where("category_id IN (?)", uc)
```

However this won't work, as it doesn't have a category_id in the product table directly. But how can I change this to use the joint table categorizations?

I'm giving you the model details, maybe you find it helpful for answering my question:

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :category

 def self.from_users_or_categories_followed_by(user)
 cf = user.category_ids
 uf = user.friend_ids

 where("user_id IN (?)", uf) # Products out of friend_ids (uf) works fine, but how to extend to categories (cf) with an OR clause?
 end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :categorizations
 has_many :products, through: :categorizations
 has_many :category_friendships
 has_many :users, through: :category_friendships
```

**Categorization.rb**

```
class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :category
 belongs_to :product
```

**Category_friendship.rb**

```
class CategoryFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :category
```

**User.rb**

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_many :category_friendships
has_many :categories, through: :category_friendships

def feed
 Product.from_users_or_categories_followed_by(self) #this should aggregate the Products
end
```

If you need more details to answer, please feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the associations you have defined and simplifying things.  Doing a bit refactoring in what we have to achieve.

**Product.rb**

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category

 end
```

**User.rb**

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :categories, through: :category_friendships
        scope :all_data , includes(:categories => [:products])

   def get_categories
     categories
   end

   def feed
      all_products = Array.new
      get_categories.collect {|category| category.get_products }.uniq
   end
  end
```

**Category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, through: :category_friendships
 has_many :products

 def get_products
   products
 end
end
```

**NO NEED OF CREATING CATEGORY_FRIENDSHIP MODEL ONLY A JOIN TABLE IS NEEDED WITH NAME CATEGORIES_FRIENSHIPS WHICH WILL JUST HAVE USER_ID AND CATEGORY_ID**

**USAGE: UPDATED**

Controller

```
  class UserController < ApplicationController
         def index
           @all_user_data = User.all_data
        end
   end
```

view index.html.erb

```
<% for user in @all_user_data %>
 <% for products in user.feed %>
  <% for product in products %>
       <%= product.name %>
     end
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried this out, but I don't see this solve my problem:
for example: let's say 'categories_first_user' retrieves categories 3 and 4.
Then your last line will show me a product in category 3 but misses the products in category 4. I think there should be something like categories_first_user.products or .all.products but this leaves me to a undefined method error.

I also have difficulties to imagine how to include your approach in my where statement in my method "self.from_users_and_categories_followed_by(user)" in my Product model.

Comment: aha.. try out: First Initialize  **products_array = Array.new** then do **categories_first_user.collect {|category| products_array << category.products }**

Comment: Thank you @Ankit! It seems to work (I think I have some doublets).
 But I can't see how to apply this to my method, so I can retrieve both the user's friends products(working with the where statement in the Product.rb) and/or the user's category products (your solution). Do you have any idea how to handle this? Thanks!!

Comment: to handle the doublets values simple do
**categories_first_user.collect {|category| products_array << category.products }.uniq**
a uniq at the end

Comment: @StonJarks: don't forget to vote up the solution if it helped you :)

Comment: Still trying to figure out how to apply this! Just can't generate my feed method!

Comment: @StonJarks updated my solution to accomodate feed with my solution

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me. And sorry for being such a noob - but where do you put the "all_user_data" lines in?

Comment: Awesome! Unfortunately this leads to a "undefined method `name' for #<User:0xb616c04>" Error. However, I can verify that the feed method should work through the console, so I must have a error somewhere else.

Comment: name was just the example i used. u have to check what attributes/column ur table has

Comment: I know, but this happens with my table names. As I told you, I can verify this should work in the console, so I think I might have some problems in my view or controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've upvoted Ankits answer but I realized there is a more elegant way of handeling this:

given:

```
u = User.first
uc = u.category_ids
```

then I can retrieve the products out of the categories by using:

```
products = Product.joins(:categories).where('category_id IN (?)', uc)
```